# gson, parent <-> child circular reference

Tags: java, android, gson

I have a problem with serialization of my objects. Below follows a simplified example:

```
public class Parent {
  private String name;
  private String id;
  private List<Child> children;

  public Parent (String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children;
    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  // getters and setters

  }
}

public class Child {
  private name;
  private parent;
  private id;

  public Child(String name, Parent parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
    id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

Let's then say that i run the following code:

```
Parent mother = new Parent(BigMoma);
Child baby = new Child(Cutie);
mother.getChildren.add(baby); //you get the concept
```

This makes the objects have a reference to each other, thus rendering the impossible to serialize with a standard Gson call.

I have also tried to use a Gson adapter that would look something like this:

```
public class ChildSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Child> {
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(Child src, Type typeOfSrc, 
JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
    result.add("name", new JsonPrimitive(src.getName()));
    result.add("id", new JsonPrimitive(src.getId()));
    result.add("parentId", new JsonPrimitive(src.getParent().getId()));

    return result;
}
```

This has not had the desired effect when running:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Child.class, new 
ChildSerializer()).create();
        String serializedDatabaseObject = gson.toJson(baby);
```

What Am I doing wrong? What can I do?

Comment: Your registering EventSerializer, not PlayerSerializer !?

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out to me. Bad copy/paste on my behalf. Post has been updated.